# remove before all element of an array of the empty element

Tags: jquery

I want to remove all the element of an array that are before the empty array include empty array in jquery

```
Actual array = ["Color 1", "Color 2", "", "Beige", "Blue", "Pink"]
```

I want remove all the element that lies before  `empty array ("")`

**Resultant array should be**

```
 ["Beige", "Blue", "Pink"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** and **[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** methods.

```js
 array = ["Color 1", "Color 2", "", "Beige", "Blue", "Pink"];

 array.splice(0, array.indexOf("") + 1)

 console.log(array)
```

---

**UPDATE :** If empty string can contain space then use **[`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** method.

```js
array = ["Color 1", "Color 2", "", "Beige", "Blue", "Pink"];

array.splice(0, array.findIndex(function(v) {
  return v.trim() == "";
}) + 1);

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : take index of empty value and use slice

```js
array = ["Color 1", "Color 2", "", "Beige", "Blue", "Pink"];
var index = array.indexOf("");
array = array.slice(index + 1);
alert(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **slice** function

```js
var array = ["Color 1", "Color 2", "", "Beige", "Blue", "Pink"];
array =array.slice(array.indexOf('') + 1);
console.log(array);
```